# Smart contract holds USDT

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, erc-20, usdt, dai

My smart contract holds some USDT token and now if someone knows my Contract address can he/she transfer that USDT to his/her address.

Just to clarify the USDT contract has transferfrom function which transfer money from one address to another

Answer (score 1):

If your the `transfer` method doesn't have any access restriction most probabaly the answer is YES, he/she can transfer that USDT. If you want to prevent such malicious activities I recommend you to check [this page of the OpenZeppelin's documentation](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/5.x/access-control)

Comment: This is the contract code of USDT
https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code

USDT contract have not added ownable in there function

Comment: Actualy they have but theirs is not that strigt forward. You can even check the function whit which they update the owner here => https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#writeContract#F12

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your contract code. If the contract calls `token.transfer`, or `token.transferFrom` it is **possible**. You would need to check if the parameters to those calls are manipulable.

More generically if your contract can call an arbitrary contract, or delegatecall a contract it might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your contract code of couse, there are variety use of this function like in the uniswap 1inch swap and liquidity mining